# How to find out if JBOSS is installed on a machine (Mac)?

Tags: macos, mac, jboss

I need to install Jboss, but I don't remember whether I have already installed it. How do I find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example in Terminal:

> sudo find / -name jboss

will list all files/dirs starting with jboss

Comment: I would propose to search for "jboss*" (with quotes) - at least on Linux without '*' these command finds only exact mach for string.